# How to use AWS Rekognition service to detect text in image with javascript

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-rekognition

i want to use Aws rekognition service to detect text in image with java script..Kindly tell me procedure to do it.

Comment: Read AWS Documentation for starters : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/text-detecting-text-procedure.html

Answer (score 1):

See: [Class: AWS.Rekognition — AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Rekognition.html#detectText-property):

> `detectText(params = {}, callback) ⇒ AWS.Request`
>
> Detects text in the input image and converts it into machine-readable text.

Please note that this is useful for pulling out bits of text from an image (eg signs, name of a book, words on a drink can) but is *not* suitable for OCR on a whole page of text.